# How to bypass Forefront TMG for downloading from Adobe Cloud

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-ftmg-2010

I hope that this question has not been asked as I've spent a couple of days googling around trying to find a solution.

I have one computer that needs to download from Adobe Cloud to install applications like Photoshop etc...

The issue I'm having is that Adobe uses a download manager program (AdobeApplicationManager.exe) that just keeps incrementing the time left on the download of any app like Photoshop.

Is there a way to allow just the download manager from that one computer to bypass any filtering settings in Forefront TMG 2010?

I have very little knowledge of servers / ISA servers / Forefront TMG and have been thrown into this position by luck I guess.

Any help with this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got TMG set to inspect downloads (ie Scan for Malware). You need to disable that for the Adobe downloads to work correctly. Side note: You don't have to use Adobe's Updater, you can just download the update files from Adobe too.

From [Technet - Defining exemptions to malware inspection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd441080.aspx)

> To specify destinations and sources exempt from malware inspection
>
> 1. In the Forefront TMG Management console, in the tree, click the Web Access Policy node.
> 2. On the Tasks tab, click Configure Malware Inspection.
> 3. Click the Destination Exceptions tab or the Source Exceptions tab, and then click Add.
> 4. In the Add Network Entities dialog box, click New, and then select the exempted network objects. You can specify an entire network,
>      computers or IP addresses, or domain name sets and URL sets. If you
>      select domain names, ensure they can be resolved by Domain Name System
>      (DNS).
> 5. To modify the default domain set (destination exemptions only) or other exempted network objects, select the appropriate entry, and then
>      click Edit.
> 6. To remove sites from the exemption list, select the appropriate entry, and then click Remove.
> 7. When you have finished, click OK, and then on the Apply Changes bar, click Apply.